# Feed Me plugin not mapping Neo fields

Tags: plugin-feedme, plugin-neo

I have Neo fields in my entries which I want to be populated by a JSON feed pulled in through Feed Me, im using elementApi top create the JSON feed.

The Feed Me setup runs fine and there are no errors. My issue is that I'm un-able to map the Neo Fields when it comes to the configuration screen (where you select the Feed Element from your fields to map with the JSON fields), because I am only seeing the top-level of the Neo fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just by the way, Neo is currently not supported with Feed Me. You're welcome to upvote this feature request - https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/issues/335